# Button with round corner and indentation effect

Tags: android

How I can achieve such type of button on Android?

[image]

P.S. I don't see a problem to make round corners, but what should I do with this indentation effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a drawable that you want as button's background.
drawable can make using a image editor like photoshop